# webotp not working [DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled.]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webapi, webotp-api

Followed https://web.dev/web-otp 100% ✔️
Followed SMS format ✔️
SMS was receiving from known and unknown number(tested both cases).✔️
Tried different code samples ✔️
Chrome app up to date ✔️

Problem: I am able to see Allow button after receiving sms. but not able to see otp and auto fill.
Error: DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled

deployed both code sample on netlify, still doesn't work..

Vanilla js  = [demo](https://webotpjs.netlify.app/)  Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-waterfall-p752m2
React js = [demo](https://webotptest.netlify.app/)   Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pine-v5q2kf

Sample SMS format, tried all these format,

> Your OTP is : 123456
> @https://example.com #123456

> Your OTP is : 123456
> @www.example.com #123456

> Your OTP is : 123456
> @example.com #123456

somehow this demo is working for me. i copied same code and deployed on netlify its not working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kapilrc-web-otp-demo-jsfh2
https://csb-jsfh2.netlify.app/

Comment: @jcalz can you help